# Laravel HTTP Client - method chaining issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have been using the HTTP client in Laravel 8, as follows:

```
$http = Http::asForm()->post($url, $post_data);

$response = $http->body();
```

This works great. Now I want to include a file upload as part of this request, but the file is optional. I have tried to structure my request like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $url = 'my-url';
    $post_data = $request->post();

    $http = Http::asForm();
    
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $http->attach('image', $request->file('image'));
    }
    
    $http->post($url, $post_data);

    $response = $http->body();
}
```

But this is not working. The error I am getting is: `Method Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::body does not exist.`

The `post()` method appears to be returning `Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest` instead of `Illuminate\Http\Client\Response`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = $http->post($url, $post_data)->body();

// alternatively:

$pendingRequest = $http->post($url, $post_data);
$response = $pendingRequest->body();
```

In your second code sample, you don't assign the return of `post()` to a variable. But this return value (`Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest`) is the object that defines the `body()` method. So either use a second variable (or reassign `$http`), or chain the `post()` and `body()` calls as shown above.